# Aggregation function with JDBC

Tags: jdbc

I want to find min,max and avg of around 72 columns similar to Adaptation_Luminance given in code snippet. How should i iterate through all the columns and return their avg,min and max? I have to use a while loop. But i dont know exactly how should i implement it.

stmt = conn.createStatement();

```
        String sql = "select avg(Adaptation_Luminance), min(Adaptation_Luminance) from ras;";

        ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next())
            System.out.println("Average of Adaptation Luminance  is " + rs.getFloat(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union in your queries to get all 72 column values as 72 different values.

```
select 'APAPTATION LUMINANCE' myField,avg(Adaptation_Luminance), min(Adaptation_Luminance) from ras
UNION
select 'TYPE1' myField,avg(TYPE1), min(TYPE1) from ras
UNION
select 'TYPE2' myField,avg(TYPE2), min(TYPE2) from ras
.....
UNION
select 'TYPE72' myField,avg(TYPE72), min(TYPE72) from ras
```

In your java jdbc use,

```
String sql = " SELECT 'ADAPTATION LUMINANCE' ........... , min (TYPE72) FROM RAS ";
// Note: Do not include semicolon at end of query string. In JDBC, it will cause error.

boolean isMoreRecordsAvailable = false;
ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        isMoreRecordsAvailable = rs.next();

while (isMoreRecordsAvailable )
{
      System.out.println("Average of "+rs.getString(1)+"  is " + rs.getFloat(2) + " and its Minimum value is : "+rs.getFloat(3));

      isMoreRecordsAvailable = rs.next();
}
```

You will get output like:

```
Average of APAPTATION LUMINANCE is 19.11 and its Minimum value is : 9.9
Average of TYPE1 is 11.11 and its Minimum value is 11
Average of TYPE2 is 22.22 and its Minimum value is 2
....
....
Average of TYPE72 is 72.72 and its Minimum value is 7.2
```

Comment: Prints the ASM code to generate the given class.
Usage: ASMifier [-debug] <fully qualified class name or class file name>
this error shows up when i make a query ready for 74 columns as per you instructed. I checked the query works in mysql workbench but still i am unable to check it in jdbc

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Adaptation Luminance  ,  avg(Adaptation_Luminance), max(Adaptation_Luminance) , ' at line 1

Comment: It should be `select 'APAPTATION LUMINANCE' **myField**,avg(Adaptation_Luminance), min(Adaptation_Luminance)`